# Adding a clearfix class to hook_node_view

Tags: nodes, theming

Ok, so what I want to do is to add a class of **clearfix** whenever Drupal outputs a node view with inline links.

I've been looking around and I figured [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) is what I need to alter.

Looking in node.module I find the following code:

```
$node->content['links'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'links__node',
    '#pre_render' => array('drupal_pre_render_links'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('links', 'inline')),
);

$node->content['links']['node'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'links__node__node',
    '#links' => $links,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('links', 'inline')),
);
```

So I guessed I somehow have to add a third value to this array trough my template.php file, but none of the gazillion ways I tried worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a `hook_preprocess_node()` function in your theme's template.php file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['content']['links'])) {
    $vars['content']['links']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'clearfix';
  }
}
```

Remember to clear Drupal's caches once you've added the function so the system picks it up.